# How to asynchronously download files in a specific order in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, multithreading, asynchronous

My iPhone app makes a asynchronous request with `NSURLRequest` to my site.

The response is JSON with 10 URLs to images. When I receive the asynchronous response I want to download the 10 files using a loop, creating an `NSMutableArray` of `UIImage` objects.

I tried to do this with the method `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL`, and it works but isn't asynchronous, so the user interface is blocked.

If I try to use the `NSURL` asynchronous method inside the response of this asynchronous method, when I receive the 10 responses with the images, I can't know if the images have been downloaded in order, and in my application the order is important.

What is a solution for downloading files in order, without blocking the UI?

My code:

```
// Create the request.
NSString *advertURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.myURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:advertURL]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
    timeoutInterval:60.0];

// Create url connection and fire request
imagesConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When I receive response:

```
//decode json with the urls   
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

//star the loop to downloading the ten images
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    //find image[i] url from json
    NSString *fullImage_URL = json[i][@"url"];

    //download image synchronously (this blocks the UI!!)
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImage_URL]];

    //insert image in the array
    arrayImages[i] = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Then, when I'm sure the array has 10 images and they're in order, I can start to show images on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of processing the JSON array and then looping and fetching all those images on the main thread, why not do it on a background thread. In the background, run the loop, and at the end, call another method on the main to signal the completed task.

```c
//star the loop to downloading the ten images ... in the background

dispatch_queue_t currentQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_retain(currentQueue);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0, ^(void) {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        //find image[i] url from json

        NSString *fullImage_URL = json[i][@"url"];

        //download image synchronously (this blocks the UI!!)


        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImage_URL]];

        //insert image in the array

        arrayImages[i] = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }

    // Return to main queue
    dispatch_async(currentQueue, ^{ 

        // process arrayImages now

    });

    dispatch_release(currentQueue);
});
```

To read more about the dispatch queues, check this out:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

There are many other ways to do this.  Personally, I'm a fan of using NSNotificationCenter myself, and the OBSERVER pattern.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to do this but, when i call the background method i have a warning (undeclared selector), but i have declared in my controller with its body and in the header file too. But the app crashes. If i insert ":" when i call the selector (@selector(fetchImagesInBackground:)) all works good. Why?

Comment: @user3084577 I typed out the example and didn't check for small errors.  Good that you fixed that.  But... that was a lower-quality solution, and I updated the code for a better solution.  Try that out!

Comment: ok, i solved with the first method you wrote (performSelectorInBackground). Now it works great, thanks!

Comment: @user3084577 that's good to hear.  You should check out the Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) too.  It's supposed to be more advanced and efficient (newer, better) than the performSelectorInBackground.  Anyway, happy coding.